# Amazon Redshift doing Hash Join even when joined on column that is both Dist Key and Sort Key

Tags: sql, join, amazon-web-services, hash, amazon-redshift

I have a fact table in Redshift having about 1.3 Billion rows with DISTribution key c1 and sort key c1, c2.

I need to join this table with itself with a join clause on c1 (i.e. c1 from 1st instance of table = c1 from 2nd instance of table).

As I see query plan of my query, Redshift appears to be doing a Hash Join with DS_DIST_NONE. Though DS_DIST_NONE is expected as I have both dist key and sort key on the column c1, but I expected Redshift to do a Merge Join instead of Hash Join (again because of the same reason).

I believe this is slowing down my query.

Can anyone please explain as to why Redshift may be doing a Hash Join instead of Merge Join (even though I have both DIST Key and SORT key on the joining column) and Redshift is doing DS_DIST_NONE for the query?

Comment: Why do you have both dist key and sort key on c1? dist key should be on a high cardinality column and is used to distribute the data evenly across your nodes, while sort key should be on low cardinality as it is used to allow faster scanning and skipping over your data.

Comment: Having same column("c1") as both dist key and sort key is necessary to achieve merge sort when joined on "c1". This is mentioned in Amazon Redshift docs.
Also I could not understand as to why low cardinality of "c1" is desired in order to allow faster scanning and skipping over data. Can you please explain?

Comment: for JOIN you need to define both keys of the joined tables as distribution keys to allow collocated joins in each node. 
SORT keys are allowing faster scan of the data to find the relevant data when you filter (WHERE...). There is little benefit of having c1 as a sort key for a JOIN query. SORT keys are telling Redshift how to sort the data on the disk. It makes the meta data (min and max values for each data chunk, for example) relevant for a query to ignore most data chunks that don't have the values defined in your WHERE clause.

Comment: According to the Redshift [Best Practices Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html), using one column for both the SORT and DIST keys is a valid approach, especially if you are expecting to often join two tables. Of course, if the table is more used for filtered queries, a sort key on the column most likely to be filtered might be a better option. Both are valid approaches. As to why the query plan would not be using a merge join: there are many possible reasons. Posting the query, table schemas and EXPLAIN is the first step to debugging.

Comment: It turned out that since we were not inserting data in our table in sorted order (as defined by Sort Key of that table) and Redshift does not automatically keep table's rows sorted by Sort Key, there was no way for Redshift to perform Merge Join on our table. After running a Full Vacuum on table, Redshift started performing Merge Join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that since we were not inserting data in our table in sorted order (as defined by Sort Key of that table) and Redshift does not automatically keep table's rows sorted by Sort Key, there was no way for Redshift to perform Merge Join on our table. After running a Full Vacuum on table, Redshift started performing Merge Join